# "Always allow" option missing from Google Family Link

Tags: google-family-link

I have my four kids set up on Google Family Link, which is a parental-control tool. I like to be able to use the option of Always Allow. This works for three of the kids.

For one of the kids, the only two options are No limit and Blocked? Where are the other two options?